# How to set xAxis maxRange/minRange for each rangeSelector button separately

Tags: javascript, highcharts

how I can set the xAxis maxRange(minRange) for each rangeSelector button separately?

For example: When I click on rangeSelector button "Day bars", I would like to set xAxis extremes for zoom in to 10days(so 10days or 10bars will be the minim for zoom in, which will be show in plot area) and for zoom out to 60days(60days or 60bars will be maximum for zoom out, which will be show in plot area). When I click on rangeSelector button with "Week bars", I would like to set xAxis extremes for zoom in to 10weeks(so 10weeks or 10bars will be the minim for zoom in, which will be show in plot area) and for zoom out to 60weeks(60weeks or 60bars will be maximum for zoom out, which will be show in plot area).

Could I use somehow maxRange,minRange functions in rangeSelector?
Could I set in chart event, rangeSelector event or xAxis event?
I tried to set it through xAxis afterSetExtremes event, but is not working.

```
xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
      events: {
        afterSetExtremes: 
          function(e)                                                         
          {
            if (e.trigger == "rangeSelectorButton" && e.rangeSelectorButton.text == "Day")
            {
              console.log("day");

              var maxDistance = 1 * 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000; //1 months time
              var xaxis = this;
              if ((e.max - e.min) > maxDistance) {
                var min = e.max - maxDistance;
                var max = e.max;
                window.setTimeout(function() {
                  xaxis.setExtremes(min, max);
                }, 1);
              }
            }
            if (e.trigger == "rangeSelectorButton" && e.rangeSelectorButton.text == "Week")
            {
              console.log("Week");
            
              var maxDistance = 12 * 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000; //12 months time
              var xaxis = this;
              if ((e.max - e.min) > maxDistance) {
                var min = e.max - maxDistance;
                var max = e.max;
                window.setTimeout(function() {
                  xaxis.setExtremes(min, max);
                }, 1);
              }
            } 
            
          },
      
      }
    }
```

Please see jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/PaulJaker/mrgk5s19/120/

Thank you a lot.
Paul

Answer (score 0):

Try to write a custom functionality for each button to achieve it, for example for the days try to do something like this:

```
{
          text: 'Day',
          dataGrouping: {
            forced: true,
            units: [
              ['day', [1]]
            ]
          },
          events: {
            click(e) {
              e.preventDefault();

              const maxDistance = 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000 * 10; // where 10 is the days amount
              const min = chart.xAxis[0].min;

              window.setTimeout(function() {
                chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(min, min + maxDistance);
              }, 1);

            }
          }
        },
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2bf5tp0h/

Comment: Hi Sebastian,
thank you for your feedback and suggestion.
This code working only for the click.After click to rangeSelector button it show the specific range, but when I zoom the range is exceeded...

Paul.

Comment: `but when I zoom the range is exceeded` I don't understand - the zoom should change the extremes, that's how the zoom works

Comment: Let me appology for misunderstanding. If, we look for your example the range 10days can not be exceeded, 10days is the maximum to see in plot area for "Day button". It can be possible to zoom in within range from 10days to specified minimum (for example 3days).

Comment: I am afraid that still, it doesn't enough clear to me. After click the `day button` the extremes are set for the 10 days range and now would you like to block the zoom functionality to keep the range for 10 days?

Comment: Yes, exactly. After click to "day button", the zoom functionality will be blocked to keep maximum range for 10 days and minimum range for 3days(for example).

Comment: It need to be blocked, because in big dataset the performance is realy slow, because all datas could be visible in plot area, therfore I want block it, the minimum range is just because of nicer visual .

Comment: I think that the easiest solution for this case is disabling the navigator handles which disables the zoom and relay only on the buttons to set the range: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/navigator.handles Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7n4va5wb/

Comment: Hi Sebastian,
thank you, but this solution is not usable. 
The zoom and navigator are needed for using after click to rangeSelector button. 
I want to only block zoom to specific maxRange for each rangeSelector button..

Thanks.